# Dynamics CRM Managed Solution Add Customer Set Parameters

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm creating a solution which will be released as a managed solution for Dynamics CRM Online.
However, the customer will need to put information in when installing the managed solution to allow interaction with outside services.
For example, when you install the LinkedIn solution, you need to add your log in information to allow the CRM to access your LinkedIn account.

How do I add these parameters to the a solution, and then allow the customer to update them if they change?

Cheers

Edit:
To add to my query and following the answer below.
To make sure the process is correct in my head.

Option 1.
I will create a custom entity for storing key/value, or username/password combination.
I would then create a customisation page for the solution using html web resource, which when submitted, javascript would create a single record to hold those values.

I then need to link every record that needs the values stored in the custom record - I'm not sure how this would be done without editing a workflow after the storage record has been created, to link each normal record to the storage one.

Option 2.
Create an xml web resource that stores the values. Create the html/javascript resources to update this using the configuration page.
I can then use a javascript function to obtain that data when the custom entity is created, perhaps to populate hidden fields for storage and use behind the scenes.
I can't find any tutorials on getting started with using xml in this way - can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I typically create a "Configuration" entity that has Name/Value attributes.  This is also useful when you have Dev/Test/Prod environments that require different configs (e.g. URLs, credentials, etc).

Another approach is to [using Plug-in configurations or Web Resources](http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.com/2011/09/adding-configuration-to-plugins-in-crm.html) to store that type of information.  The Plug-in configuration is pretty straightforward *if* you can have the customer use the Plug-in Registration tool to modify the value.

Comment: I think Chris' point was that he wanted the data to be installed as part of the solution (correct me if I'm wrong Chris), so while the Configuration entity is a perfectly laudable design decision (and one I use myself) it doesn't solve the issue of config data portability.

Comment: ..and regarding the plug-in configuration this *does* potentially allow config data to be installed (only Unsecure config is included in the solution though - anything in Secure Config of the registration step will need to be rekeyed after install). The downside of this is that the user needs access to the Plugin Registration tool in order to view or update the config.

Comment: I want the data to be added by the customer after the solution is installed, for example to hold their third party log in details which they wouldn't want to give us to build the solution complete for them.

Comment: Just to note that i've added more information to my initial question for clarification (hopefully)

Comment: Option 1: I used REST and JSON + JQuery in JavaScript to lookup my name/value pairs
Option 2: I haven't done it personally, but the [Silverlight Bing Map](http://mapsforcrm2011.codeplex.com/) in Codeplex uses Web Resources for configuration similar to what you are describing

Comment: Jamiey Miley just posted sample code that does the [HTML/JScript approach](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-build-htmljscript-configuration.html)

Comment: Chris Snyder is correct - create an entity that can hold the values, and add an information page to the solution to set values. That information page will need to do some sort of data lookup to set values such as REST or JSON.